# Vuex getter is undefined however store has correct data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am mutating data and confirmed the $store is correctly updated however the getter stays undefined. I am using vue-dev-tools to troubleshoot. I call `FETCH_ENDPOINTS` from the first component that is loaded.

Fun Fact:
If I close the browser and cold load the app the getter has the data. If I refresh the page, the getter is undefined.

Vuex Module:

```
const getters = {
  agentEndpoints: state => state.agent.agentEndpoints
};

export const actions = {
  [FETCH_ENDPOINTS](context) {
    CcpService.getEndpoints().then(endpoints => {
      console.log("action: " + JSON.stringify(endpoints)); // This has the right data!
      context.commit(SET_ENDPOINTS, endpoints);
    });
  }
};

export const mutations = {
  [SET_ENDPOINTS](state, endpoints) {
    console.log("mutation: " + JSON.stringify(endpoints)); // This has the right data!
    state.agent.agentEndpoints = endpoints;
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi what is the datatype of 'agentEndpoints' ?

Comment: Hi - agentEndpoints is an array

Comment: hmmm interesting are you updating a particular index of the array ?

Comment: Perhaps `state.agent` or `state.agent.agentEndpoints` is not being observed by Vue? How is `state.agent` initially set? Check out [Change Detection Caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

Comment: could not reproduce, but a bit of immutability does not hurt: https://codesandbox.io/s/1r697n04lj